# SVG not showing correctly on Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, window

I know there are similar questions like this, but I can't really make out what to change it the code.

Here the link:
[SVG](http://www.pluskat.de/wp-content/themes/pluskat/images/mehrwert.svg)

It's being opened in a Window with 1024px X 768px. At leasts that's what I read out of the code. Follow this link and click onto the picture with the blue heads on the left, to make it open like it usually does for users. Link: [Homepage](http://www.pluskat.de)

I read I would have to define width and height 100% to make it work, but I don't know where to write it to. 
Here's the code I found:

```
<div style="position:relative; top:8px;">
<a title="Hier finden Sie eine kurzpräsentation über die Werbeagentur Pluskat GmbH" onclick="javascript: window.open('<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/mehrwert.svg', 'Mehrwert', 'width=1024px,height=768px,scrollbars=no');" href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/ images/kurz_praesi.jpg" alt="SVG Präsentation" width="237" height="160" border="0" title="Das können wir für Sie tun - 150 Sekunden Kurzpräsentation" /></a>
<p style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:11px; line-height:17px;color: #000000;">Was wir für Sie tun können, erfahren Sie auch in unserer knapp 3-minütigen Präsentation.<br/> <strong>
<a title="Hier finden Sie eine kurzpräsentation über die Werbeagentur Pluskat GmbH" onclick="javascript: window.open('<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/mehrwert.svg', 'Mehrwert', 'width=1024,height=768,scrollbars=no');" href="#"><span>Einfach durchklicken.</span></a></strong><br/>
</p></div>
```

That's the whole code calling up the window with the SVG within. It works fine on every Browser, except Firefox. Firefox somehow covers it with white lines / cuts it. 
WOuld be great if anyone had an answer and could somehow highlight it for me in the code.

Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I'm guessing that you need to go into the mehrwert.svg file, and change this part of the `<svg>` element

```
width="1022" height="766"
```

to

```
width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 1022 766"
```

Comment: Hello Michael. Thanks for your reply. This question might sound stupid, but how did you find out the width and height of the svg? U downloaded it somehow or found it in the code? Because I can't find it..

Comment: It's in the svg file - remember svg files aren't binary files, they're XML files, so you can crack it open in a text editor and edit it.